# Какой способ организации сайта лучше?

Tags: php

Помогите, люди добрые!

Какой способ лучше?

1 Способ:

```
файл index.php и т.д.
код:

..
include('top.php');
include('footer.php');
..
```

2 Способ:

```
url: index.php?file=page1
код:

..
include('top.php');
include('footer.php');
include($_GET['file']);
..
```

Comment: Мой уровень **IQ** не позволяет понять этот **QR-код**. Не могли бы вы расшифровать своими словами эти "два способа"?

Comment: Как я понимаю вы хотите реализовать FrontController index.php, если да, то посмотрите исходники PHP фреймворков

Comment: догадываюсь почему, прям возбуждаюсь, при виде этой строки: include($_GET['file']);  // ))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
include($_GET['file']);
```

Если такой вид останется в продакшене - то лучше конечно первый - он не вызывает код, который можно переинстанцировать и получить доступ к файловой системе через него. А так способ хорош, но при грамотном использовании. А вообще читайте про паттерны проектирования - они дадут много полезной информации для разработки. На основе оных Вы получите навыки по грамотному подключению (главное - динамическому) необходимых данных и вообще разовьёте смекалку и обаяние :)